# Postgres avoid Trigger on delete cascade

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, cascade

Hello i have a problem with a *Trigger*

i have 2 *tables*:

- t_mandant
- t_user_has_mandant

when i *delete* a row in **t_user_has_mandant** i call a *trigger* beforeDeleteUserMandant()
but i need a possibility to ignore the trigger call when i delete a *mandant* from **t_mandant**

because **t_user_has_mandant** has a *foreign key* on **t_mandant** which is on *delete cascade*.

im using postgres 8.4

Comment: So, you want to change the logic of a trigger on `t_user_has_mandant` if the delete was caused by `CASCADE` FK from `t_mandant`?

Comment: yes just do nothing in the trigger or ignore it completely

Comment: @SerYoga, did you ever find a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Read [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) page of the manual.

Using the variable

> TG_TABLE_NAME
>
> Data type name; the name of the table that caused the
>   trigger invocation.

You can determine if the `DELETE` was from `t_user_has_mandant` or `t_mandant`.

Comment: i tried it: RAISE NOTICE 'table_name: %', TG_TABLE_NAME; the result was NOTICE:  table_name: t_user_has_mandant  but my sql query was delete from t_mandant where id_mandant = 555 ...

Comment: Hm. Maybe. I havent tested my ansver.

Comment: The other (but a bit ugly) way is to query `pg_stat_activity` view to get the text of current query and search for table names in it.

Comment: i think its to overelaborate :(